# Edit figure numbering in LyX

Tags: graphics, floats, cross-referencing, lyx

I am beginner to `LaTeX` and `LyX` as well. I am writing my survey report and got an issue with labeling the figures.

I first inserted a figure float and then the picture.Once I add a float it names that float as `"Figure 1"`. After that, it cannot be changed. But I need to change it something like `Figure 1.3.2`.

The caption of the figure can be edited, but the figure numbering cannot. 
How to do this?

Comment: In LaTeX, the idea is that the numbers of floats are handled automatically. This avoids a lot of common errors. If you go to Document > Settings > Modules and add "Number Figures by Section", then compile. Does it work for you? Note that often the output in PDF is different from that in LyX so always test with the compiled (PDF) document.

Comment: This is not as easy in LyX. You'll have to resort to the creation of a new layout (quite extreme), or some ERT insertions.